# Write a Plugin. Should I know clearly about the function defined by gazebo if I want to write a plugin by myself?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I read about the tutorial of Write a Plugin. I don't understand the functions listed by the tutorial. Do you think I should learn about the header files first?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17048/write-a-plugin.-should-i-know-clearly-about-the-function-defined-by-gazebo-if-i-want-to-write-a-plugin-by-myself?/) by [Ji Cai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3683/ji-cai/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo's API is quite extensive, so it's probably not viable to "learn" all the functions. Depending on your use case, only a fraction of the functions will be relevant. For example, if you want to apply forces and velocities to parts of your robot, you'd need some functions from [gazebo::physics::Link](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html) API. To tune a camera sensor, you'd look at [gazebo::sensors::CameraSensor](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1sensors_1_1CameraSensor.html) and so on.

Instead of going through the API, I suggest you search for keywords related to the problem you're trying to solve and go through some related tutorials and examples first. This way, you naturally start becoming familiar with the functions.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ji Cai](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3683/ji-cai/) on 2017-08-29**:
Thank you for your answer. It really helps me out!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-08-30**:
Glad to help :) Be sure to mark the answer as correct if that was enough for you, so other users can know in the future.